# Error: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to call data from firestore but i have hit a problem. it keeps giving me this error even though every source of a solution i have seen use 'documents' to locate the particular data that is needed. help is needed very much

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


class BoardApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const BoardApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BoardApp> createState() => _BoardAppState();
}

class _BoardAppState extends State<BoardApp> {
   var firestoreDb = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('board').snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('community board'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestoreDb,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, int index){
                return Text(snapshot.data?.documents[index]);
                }
            );
          }else{
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          }
      ),
    );
```

i have done everything that is needed but i still get the error

Comment: I have posted an answer. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` to access the data from firestore by replacing `StreamBuilder()`.

A QuerySnapshot is returned from a collection query, and allows you to inspect the collection, such as how many documents exist within it, and gives access to the documents within the collection.

You can refer the [document](https://dev.to/kazuhideoki/how-to-get-data-from-firestore-and-show-it-on-flutterbuilder-or-streambuilder-e05) & [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)